# NullReferenceException in C# when dealing with Streams?

Tags: c#, networking, object, nullreferenceexception

So, I'm pretty new to all this network programming, and I have a few questions...

I'm building a client-server chat application, wherein the server is running, the client(s) connect(s) to the server, and then when a client sends a message to the server, the server relays it to all the clients. The server is a console application, and the client is a Windows Form Application.

The error I'm getting is in my client, at the very top of my form, I have a textbox to take in a user's name and a button to "submit" it and connect to the server with that username.

Anyways, this is my button connect code:

```
    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        readData = "Connecting to chat server...";
        msg();

        try
        {
            sck_client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
            sw = new StreamWriter(sck_client.GetStream());
            string toSend = txtUsername.Text;

            sw.Write(toSend);
            sw.Flush();

            chatThread = new Thread(GetMessages);
            chatThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            readData = ex.ToString(); 
            msg();
        }
    }
```

msg() quite simply takes the value in readData and prints it to the screen (in a richtextbox). sw is a streamwriter that has been declared publicly, outside of the method, so is sck_client (a TcpClient) and chatThread (a Thread).

Basically, the issue is, when I run my program and try to connect, it throws Exception ex, as though it cannot connect. It throws a NullReferenceException with the text:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. at Chat_Client.Main.btnConnect_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in filepath\Chat_Client\Main.cs:line36

That occurs even when my server is running and listening to port 8888. So, what should I do to fix it?

If you need any more of my code to solve the problem, let me know in a comment and I'll post it.

To show where the code is instantiated:

```
public partial class Main : Form // new class for the form itself
    {
        // all of these are declared outside any method:
        TcpClient sck_client = default(TcpClient);
        Thread chatThread = default(Thread);
        string readData = null;
        StreamWriter sw = default(StreamWriter);
        StreamReader sr = default(StreamReader);
        ...
```

Comment: which one is line 36?

Comment: Line 36 and everything around it would be good.

Comment: What are you doing in `msg()` , in the first call sw might be invalid as its initialized later in the code ?

Comment: Line 36 is where I attempt to connect the socket (line 8 in the code I already posted): "sck_client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);".
---------
msg(), as I mentioned before, simply updates the rich text box (which is what I'm using to display the new message), its simply a matter of appending text, mostly from the readData string.

Comment: are you able to who us, in relation to the code shown, where `sck_client` is instantiated?

Comment: Looks like the exception is thrown directly in your event handler, does sck_client refer to null?

Comment: @AlastairPitts I've updated it so you can see where it was instantiated, they're declared outside any method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TcpClient sck_client = default(TcpClient);
...
sck_client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
```

at some point, you will need to give it a value other than `null` (the `default` for `TcpClient` is `null`). Also, you probably don't need a `StreamWriter` just to send a `string` - I'd look at using `Encoding` (to get the bytes; typically UTF8), and a length-prefix of the size (in bytes).

Answer (score 4):

Ok, this line is your problem:

```
TcpClient sck_client = default(TcpClient);
```

specifically:

```
default(TcpClient);
```

`default()` will return the default value for a given type. If the type is a reference type (eg. class), then it will return `null`. If the type is a value type (eg. `int`) then it will attempt to set it to `0`.

The default keyword does NOT create a new instance of the the class for you, you need to the use the `new` keyword for that.

I would seriously be reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx